# Premature disposing a MessageBodyStream in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, timeout, streaming, dispose

I am using WCF to download a really long file. It is a self hosted service on net-tcp binding. On client i am reading the stream and writing it to a disk in a background thread. On UI, there is a cancel button. I cancel the read-write loop using a `CancellationToken`.

Problem is,

**if the Stream is premature (not EOF) then it takes too long to dispose it.**

at Server (c#):

```
IO.Stream getFile(string filePath) {
    return new IO.FileStream(filePath);
}
```

at client (vb):

```
using proxy as new ServiceReference1.TestServer
    using wcfStrm = proxy.getFile("c:\100MB.dat")
        using fileStrm = new FileStream("d:\destination\100MB.dat")

            dim buff(256) as new Byte

            while true
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested

                Dim len = wcfStrm.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)

                if len > 0 then
                    fileStrm.write(buff, 0, len)
                else
                    exit while
                end if
             end while

         end using      
    end using ' <-------------- this hangs for 10Mins
end using
```

When the `CancellationToken` throws `OperationCancelledException`, all the three using blocks try to dispose their resources. Now when the second using block tries to dispose the `MessageBodyStream`, then it hangs for 10 minutes. but if the stream is completely read, then it exits quickly.

i suspected, it had something to do with the `ReceiveTimeout` of 10 mins. so i changed it to 30 seconds and viola! the dispose now takes 30 seconds.

One more thing. The `Dispose` operation actually timeouts. It eats my `OperationCancelledException` and produces a `TimeoutException` saying `The sockket transfer timed out after 00:00:00... bla bla bla`

following is the stack trace

```
System.TimeoutException: The socket transfer timed out after 00:00:00. You have exceeded the timeout set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.SetReadTimeout(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean synchronous, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PreReadConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MaxMessageSizeStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.Close()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingStream.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.Close()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at ...somewhere in my code...
```

I am not convinced that once cannot cancel a stream without fully reading it. On the other hand I cannot just forget the stream and let it go without disposing. It has to be a blocking *wait-until-safely-released* call.

Can someone please help me out here?

### Edit

The stack trace shows:

```
'                                                         this is interesting
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.Close() '                    VVVVVVVVVVVVV
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
```

So i changed the using block to a `try-finally` block. there i put `wcfStrm.close` followed by `wcfStrm.Dispose`. to my astonishment, the close statement passed swiftly and the dispose timed out. Now if inside dispose the actual culprit was `Close` then why did explicit close didnt hang? and then again the dispose hanged even when the stream was closed?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, the implementation of `Stream.Dispose()` is to call `Stream.Close()`. The base implementation of `Stream.Close()` is to call `Stream.Dispose(bool)`. It's counter to the guidelines of how you would typically implement `IDisposable`, so it's worth noting.

The `MessageBodyStream.Close()` method is implemented to first close the `Message` being read, then to close the `XmlDictionaryReader` associated with the stream.

Looking at your full stack trace, the problem seems to be that this reader eventually calls into `SingletonConnectionReader.Close(TimeSpan)`. This takes a `TimeSpan` as a timeout, and this is the source of your `TimeoutException` replacing the `OperationCancelledException`.

This method attempts to read the rest of the stream to complete the close operation. I can't explain the rationale behind that, but it how it is.

---

To fix your problem, you must stop using your proxy class as you are. Despite being `IDisposable`, it's not safe to use any WCF proxy in a `using` block, because calling `Dispose()` calls `Close()`, and in the event of an exception, that's not what you mean.

In this case, calling `Abort()` on the proxy will fix the problem completely, because it's what you mean: **abort the operation.**

```
using proxy as new ServiceReference1.TestServer
    dim wcfStrm = proxy.getFile("c:\100MB.dat")

    try
        using fileStrm = new FileStream("d:\destination\100MB.dat")

            dim buff(256) as new Byte

            while true
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested

                Dim len = wcfStrm.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)

                if len > 0 then
                    fileStrm.write(buff, 0, len)
                else
                    exit while
                end if
             end while

         end using      
    end try
    catch
        proxy.Abort()
    end catch
    finally
        wcfStrm.Dispose()
    end finally
end using
```

I'm not a VB developer, so I apologise if my syntax is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider chunking your large file into smaller chunks (streams). You will still have a delay, but considerably shorter than your approach.

Comment: yes. i did thought that but i am more interested in **why** i will *still have a delay*? i understand there are workarounds. but want to know the xact problem.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what logic was planned to the 'Dispose' function

The dispose function can mean (Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx))

1. Finish the current operation and release resources
2. **Stop** the current operation and release resources

I guess so the dispose function implement '1' and the Close function implement '2'

You can check this in reflection or documentation.

I didn't check it because I don't have a clue what type is 'wcfStrm'

Comment: `wcfStrm` *is-an-instance-of* `MessageBodyStream`